# Desktop Application to Run R Scripts

Tags: r, desktop-application

I have quite a few R scripts that I run routinely and I would like to package them into a single desktop app (not a web app with Shiny) that anyone can run without an R installation. To help with simplicity, all the users that would use the application operate off of shared network drives.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to do this? I started to write an app with PyQt5 in Python but I was having trouble and it just seemed to add an extra, messy layer of complexity.

Comment: It depends on your OS, specify please.

Comment: (1) Running R off of *"network drives"*: theoretically possible but ***really very discouraged*** for many reasons. (2) Internalizing R into an app: perhaps see [*RInside*](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html). (3) This question is very much asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"*, which is unfortunately [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I wish you luck, honestly. I researched this at length several years ago but found no way short of "RInside".

Comment: Why do you reject Shiny for this task?

Comment: Yeah, Shiny is perfect to do this task, a ShinyApp can be converted to .exe file using Java and r portable.

Comment: @rodrigo-orellana Sorry, Windows 10 for all users.

Comment: @djhurio I was trying to avoid Shiny because most of the scripts access local MySQL Servers and I had the worst time trying to get that to work.

Comment: Windows Script Host can do the work, but you got to learn it.

Comment: I do not see a problem to access a local (whatever you mean by local here) MySQL through Shiny. You can create a local Shiny app.

Comment: @djhurio I’ve tried to connect many times with Shiny and FreeTDS, nothing was working.